# Android custom design Dialog prob without title bar

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, tile

I using following xml to design a custom Dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wound_screener_bg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="70dp"
        android:textColor="#5A5C5E"
        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/bodyPartText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="You selected the arm"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#727576"
        android:id="@+id/confirmText"
        android:layout_below="@id/bodyPartText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Is that correct?"/>
    <View 
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/confirmText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/buffer"></View>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YES"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:textColor="#EB9093"
        android:id="@+id/yesBtn"
        android:layout_below="@id/confirmText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buffer"/>  
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NO"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/noBtn"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:textColor="#EB9093"
        android:layout_below="@id/confirmText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buffer"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I using following code to display the dialog box.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.bodypart_comfirm);


TextView bodyPartText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bodyPartText);
Button yesBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yesBtn);
Button noBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.noBtn);

bodyPartText.setText("You selected the " + partName);

noBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
   dialog.dismiss();
 }
});     

yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
   .............
   .............

 }
});

dialog.show();
```

It gives a dialog like below.
[image]

Now if I remove the line of "dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);", it gives the proper design, but with the title-bar, but I do not the title bar.

[image]

What is the problem in my code? How to solve it?

Comment: reedit your question's subject. You got no problem removing titlebar at all. Btw: you can try using activity instead of Dialog, themed as dialog. That is usually more flexible with custom layouts

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Yes button is missing when I off the title bar.

Answer (score 1):

add this style to your styles.xml file :

```
<style name="FullHeightDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

and then instanciate your dialog with :

```
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
View contentView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.instructions_popup_layout, null);
final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this, R.style.FullHeightDialog);
dialog.setContentView(contentView);
Button button=(Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the layout as

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="70dp"
    android:textColor="#5A5C5E"
    android:paddingLeft="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/bodyPartText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="You selected the arm"/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="#727576"
    android:id="@+id/confirmText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bodyPartText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Is that correct?"/>
<View 
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/confirmText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/buffer"></View>
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YES"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:textColor="#EB9093"
    android:id="@+id/yesBtn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/confirmText"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buffer"/>  
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NO"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/noBtn"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:textColor="#EB9093"
    android:layout_below="@+id/confirmText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buffer"/>
```

Change all references like: android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buffer" to android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buffer"

Comment: Yes, there was a problem in writing, I solved it, but no change in result.